# Visual C# 2010 express edition - can't add references or items to toolbox

Tags: c#, ide, visual-c#-express-2010

I've been using Visual C# express through 2005, 2008 and 2010 editions. I'm irrationally irritated by its preference for putting Project files into different subfolders of the My Documents folder for each edition so I've recently moved the default location for Projects to a new single location My Documents\Visual Studio\Projects, this appears to have produced a problem.

As a result of moving projects around I need to re-add references to 3rd party software libraries by right-clicking the references entry in the Solution Explorer->Add reference... rather than popping up the appropriate dialog box this simply makes the application frame flash so I can't add the references.

There is a workaround:
1. Create a New Project
2. Exit Visual C# (not even necessary to save the project)
3. Open the project of interest, it is now possible to add references until Visual C# is closed.

Any ideas for a more stable fix? Is there another place in which the root directory for folders is set? Is the References dialog trying to open on a non-existent directory?

There is a similar problem with attempting to browse to add new items to the toolbox which is similarly fixed by the workaround

Comment: Never heard of that bug yet.  Use connect.microsoft.com to file a feedback report.  Or wait for SP1.

Comment: Good idea - I've just done that.